# IF EXISTS UPSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I currently have a stored procedure that updates files if they exist and inserts if they don't. The problem with the query below is it seem to be inserting all records regardless.

I can't seem to spot what the problem is?

Using SQL server 2012

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[usp_UpdateInsertOptimise_new]
@Resid int = null,
@PostCode varchar(50),
@DriverID int,
@droporder int,
@X int,
@Y int,
@Calculate bit,
@uidref bigint,
@Description1 varchar(500),
@Description2 varchar(500),
@Description3 varchar(500),
@Uiddriver int,
@reservationsid int,
@Time varchar(50),
@TimeInPoint int,
@UniqueString varchar(50),
@DistanceBetweenTwoPoints float,
@Weight int,
@TimeBetweenPoints int,
@TimeFrom datetime,
@TimeTo datetime,
@TotalDistance float,
@Display varchar(150),
@Volume float,
@VehicleID int,
@Pallets int,
@AddressId int,
@CD nvarchar(10),
@ForkLiftRequired bit,
@HazardousRequired bit,
@FridgeRequired bit,
@TailLiftRequired bit,
@CurtinsideRequired bit,
@CDID varchar(50),
@CDOrder int,
@OriginalDate datetime,
@ArivalTime datetime,
@TimeForStage int,
@Optimise bit,
@ForVehicleGroupID int,
@DepotID int

AS

if EXISTS (SELECT * FROM optimise WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
Where ReservationsID = @ResID)

BEGIN
UPDATE  dbo.Optimise SET 
PostCode = @PostCode,
[DriverID] = @DriverID,
[droporder] = @DropOrder,
[X] = @X,
[Y] = @Y,
[Calculate] = @Calculate,
[uidref] = @UIDRef,
[Description1] = @Description1,
[Description2] = @Description2,
[Description3] = @Description3,
[Uiddriver] = @UIDDriver,
[reservationsid] = @ReservationsID,
[Time] = @Time,
[TimeInPoint] = @TimeInPoint,
[UniqueString] = @UniqueString,
[DistanceBetweenTwoPoints] = @DistanceBetweenTwoPoints,
[Weight] = @Weight,
[TimeBetweenPoints] = @TimeBetweenPoints,
[TimeFrom] = @TimeFrom,
[TimeTo] = @TimeTo,
[TotalDistance] = @TotalDistance,
[Display] = @Display,
[Volume] = @Volume,
[VehicleID] = @VehicleID,
[Pallets] = @Pallets,
[AddressID] = @AddressID,
[CD] = @CD,
[ForkliftRequired] = @ForkLiftRequired,
[HazardousRequired] = @HazardousRequired,
[FridgeRequired] = @FridgeRequired,
[TailLiftRequired] = @TailLiftRequired,
[CurtinsideRequired] = @CurtinsideRequired,
[CDID] = @CDID,
[CDOrder] = @CDOrder,
[OriginalDate] = @OriginalDate,
[ArivalTime] = @ArivalTime,
[TimeForStage] = @TimeForStage,
[Optimise] = @Optimise,
[ForVehicleGroupID] = @ForVehicleGroupID,
[DepotID] = @DepotID 

WHERE ReservationsID = @ResID

END

ELSE 

IF NOT EXISTs(SELECT * FROM optimise WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
Where ReservationsID = @ResID)

BEGIN



INSERT INTO [Optimise]
([PostCode],
[DriverID],
[droporder],
[X],
[Y],
[Calculate],
[uidref],
[Description1],
[Description2],
[Description3],
[Uiddriver],
[reservationsid],
[Time],
[TimeInPoint],
[UniqueString],
[DistanceBetweenTwoPoints],
[Weight],
[TimeBetweenPoints],
[TimeFrom],
[TimeTo],
[TotalDistance],
[Display],
[Volume],
[VehicleID],
[Pallets],
[AddressId],
[CD],
[ForkliftRequired],
[HazardousRequired],
[FridgeRequired],
[TailLiftRequired],
[CurtinsideRequired],
[CDID],
[CDOrder],
[OriginalDate],
[ArivalTime],
[TimeForStage],
[Optimise],
[ForVehicleGroupID],
[DepotID] )

VALUES (
@PostCode,
@DriverID,
@DropOrder,
@X,
@Y,
@Calculate,
@UIDRef,
@Description1,
@Description2,
@Description3,
@UIDDriver,
@ReservationsID,
@Time,
@TimeInPoint,
@UniqueString,
@DistanceBetweenTwoPoints,
@Weight,
@TimeBetweenPoints,
@TimeFrom,
@TimeTo,
@TotalDistance,
@Display,
@Volume,
@VehicleID,
@Pallets,
@AddressId,
@CD,
@ForkLiftRequired,
@HazardousRequired,
@FridgeRequired,
@TailLiftRequired,
@CurtinsideRequired,
@CDID,
@CDOrder,
@OriginalDate,
@ArivalTime,
@TimeForStage,
@Optimise,
@ForVehicleGroupID,
@DepotID)


END

GO
```

Comment: Remove the second IF its superfluous. `ELSE BEGIN`

Comment: Does @ResId hold what you think it holds?.

Comment: If you run a SQL Profiler RPC:Completed trace on this proc, can you verify that the @Resid parameter is being passed in correctly?

Comment: Removed the IF. Yeah @ResID is being passed what's expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Can't see anything wrong at all so sorry if this seems patronising, back to basics though:

- Are you calling the correct SP? I notice the SP above is appended with _new `usp_UpdateInsertOptimise_new`
- Are you passing the correct ResIDs? Do they exist, have you traced these when calling the proc.
- simplify the proc to return a true/false, see which fires, remove anything not essential to just check if the ID exists or not. try switching IF EXISTS for IF NOT EXISTS see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

@ResID is defaulted to null at the top. No idea why, it didn't work because of it though!

Comment: Weird, that shouldn't cause it not to work, when specifying the parameter when calling the proc null would be replaced. Just tested that.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, which is why I didn't pick up on it. When a parameter is passed the null value becomes void?

Comment: Strange, I tested this and it seemed to operate as expected, perhaps it depends on how the proc is called. Glad you got it working though!

Comment: Yeah, bizarre! Thanks for having a look though dude :)